# NSMutable singleton question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, singleton, nsmutablearray

I would like to get some help to sort out the code I've come up with to implement a NSMutableArray singleton.

.h file

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject {

    NSMutableArray *globalArray;

}

+ (MySingleton *)instance;

- (NSMutableArray *) getArray;

- (void) addArray:(NSObject *)arrayToAdd;

- (id) init;



.m file

@implementation MySingleton


- (id) init
{
    self = [super init]; 
    globalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}


+ (MySingleton *)instance  {

    static MySingleton *instance;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!instance) {
            instance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];

        }
    }
    return instance;
}


- (NSMutableArray *) getArray{
    return globalArray;
}



- (void) addArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayToAdd
{

    [globalArray addObject:arrayToAdd];  

}
```

someviewcontroller.m

```
    MySingleton  *prodInstance = [MySingleton instance];
[prodInstance addArray:tmpArray];
NSLog(@"cnt tmpArray %i",[tmpArray count]);
NSLog(@"cnt singleton %i",[[prodInstance getArray] count]);
```

The console will display counts 3 and 1.

I thought [prodInstance getArray] will be the same as the tmpArray.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `addArray` method is putting `tmpArray` inside `globalArray`, which is apparently not what you want.

I don't think there's really any reason to have `addArray` at all -- just call `getArray` to get the global array, and work with that. For example:

```
// add all objects in tmpArray to prodInstance global array
[[prodInstance getArray] addObjectsFromArray:tmpArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `-addArray:`, you’re adding the array argument `arrayToAdd` *as a single element* in the global array. It looks like you want to add all the elements of the array argument instead, so replace

```
[globalArray addObject:arrayToAdd];
```

with

```
[globalArray addObjectsFromArray:arrayToAdd];
```

Also, since the argument doesn’t need to be a mutable array, consider changing the parameter type to `NSArray *`.